# Using a form with custom field widgets in a modelformset_factory?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to create a customized form in a modelformset_factory `using jquery.formset.js`.
Here is a code:

Customized form class:

```
class CustomizedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(widget=JQueryUIDatepickerWidget, required=True )
    time_begin = forms.TimeField(widget=JQueryUITimePickerWidget, required=True, initial=time(0, 0))
    time_end = forms.TimeField(widget=JQueryUITimePickerWidget, required=True, initial=time(23,59))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomizedForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Custom formset class:

```
class FormSetWithInitialValues(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, initials, **kwargs):
        super(FormSetWithInitialValues, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.initials = initials

    def save_new(self, form, commit=True):
        for k, val in self.initials.items():
            form.cleaned_data[k] = val
        return form.save(commit=commit)
```

Formset factory:

```
Formset = modelformset_factory(
                    MyModel,
                    formset=FormSetWithInitialValues,
                    form=CustomizedForm,
                    can_delete=True,
                    extra=1,
                )
```

The problem is next. When i init page all existing formsets initialize with widgets. But when I try to add new form to formset the form is create, but widgets don't tie with form's fields. The question is, how to tie widgets with new form's fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solving is next. When we add a new form to formset, jquery just copies hidden html row corresponding to form fields, cleans it, and gives new ids. But it doesn't copy information about widgets. So we should use js-callback function which is called after new form to formset add:

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.formset/jquery.formset.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    {% if formset %}
        var datepickerConfig = {};
        datepickerConfig.__proto__ = DatePickerConfig;
        var timepickerConfig = {};
        timepickerConfig.__proto__ = TimePickerConfig;

        $('.calendar_formset_tr').formset({
            prefix : '{{ formset.prefix|escapejs }}',
            deleteText: '&nbsp;<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/icons/delete.png" />',
            addText: '&nbsp;<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/icons/add.png" />',
            addCssClass: 'add_link',
            deleteCssClass: 'remove_link',
            added: function (row) {
                var datePicker = $(row).find('input[name$="date"]');
                if (datePicker.length > 0) {
                    //привязка виджета
                    datePicker.datepicker('destroy').datepicker(datepickerConfig);
                }

                var timeBeginPicker = $(row).find('input[name$="time_begin"]');
                var timeEndPicker = $(row).find('input[name$="time_end"]');
                if (timeBeginPicker.length > 0 && timeEndPicker.length > 0) {
                    //привзяка виджета и проставление значения по-умолчанию
                    timeBeginPicker.val("00.00");
                    timeBeginPicker.timepicker('destroy').timepicker(timepickerConfig);
                    timeEndPicker.val("23.59");
                    timeEndPicker.timepicker('destroy').timepicker(timepickerConfig);
                }
            }
        });
    {% endif %}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Has django modelFormFactory javascript code that automatically add new forms to html formset? Can you send to me a link where this is documented or explained?

Comment: I think you can look it [here](http://elo80ka.wordpress.com/2009/10/10/jquery-plugin-django-dynamic-formset/)

Comment: Nice, but this information should be included in your question. Your question should have begun by "I use Django Dynamic Formset and ...". This is the reason that nobody has replied your question.

Answer (score 0):

Tural,

I don't understand your question. But, I post this bit of my code. I hope this can help to you. This is a first approach, we can refine answer.

```
formset_f = modelformset_factory(  ItemQualitativa, extra=20 )

if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = formset_f(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
else:
    formset = formset_f()

for form in formset:
    form.fields['text'].widget.attrs['size'] = 70 #<-try change widget here.
```

That I don't understand about your question is this sentence: "But when I try to add new form to formset the form is create". When do tou try to add new forms?

regards.

Comment: Thanks danihp for your answer. In that sentence I mean to say about adding new formset element. Because formset contains forms, i wrote 'when I try to add new form to formset'

Comment: Has django modelFormFactory javascript code that automatically add new forms to html formset? Can you send to me a link where this is documented or explained?